# JPA Strange behaivor when updating embeddable

Tags: jpa

My problem is when iam trying to update an object with an embeddable class. If i watch the values, it seems the embeddable values are there. But the code throw an exception telling that that values are empty. And when i watch in the debugger, the object has de values but when i inspect the content in the exception, the object seems not having the values.

```
public abstract class ItemOrcamento extends EntidadeAuditavel {

    @Embedded   private ConfiguracaoColeta configuracaoColeta = new ConfiguracaoColeta();

}
```

[image: Showing that in variable 'orcamento' the value of 'responsavelColeta' is CQA]

And after the em.flush() it throws the exception InvalidStateException and when i search to look for the variables its appears this:

[image: After flush]

Comment: Please rad the tag-descriptions. "embedded" is **not** the same as "embedding" (or what you might have thought of).

Comment: @Olaf did you understand my problem? instead of correcting anuseful things, try to help, dude!

Comment: The tag are relevant to sort things. Take the [tour] - dude! My comment was just a friendly hint next time to choose tags carefully. EOT